# Change location of innodb_temporary

Tags: innodb, mysql-8.0, tempdb

I want to change the path where the `ibtmp1` is stored in mysql 8.0.25 on debian 11. How to do this? I see:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME='innodb_temporary'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             FILE_ID: 4294967293
             FILE_NAME: ./ibtmp1
```

I changed `mysqld.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_tmpdir=/$newDir/
innodb_temporary=/$newDir/
innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir=/$newDir/
innodb_temp_data_file_path=/$newDir/
```

restarted `mysqld` but that doesn't change a thing.
Same with:

```
mysql> SELECT @@innodb_temp_data_file_path;
+------------------------------+
| @@innodb_temp_data_file_path |
+------------------------------+
| ibtmp1:12M:autoextend        |
+------------------------------+
```

Only if I change in the `init.d` script:

> mysqld_safe --innodb-tmpdir=/$newDir/

I see with `mysql> SELECT @@innodb_tmpdir;` that the path is set (which unfortunately doesn't affect the path of `ibtmp1`.

I am unsure if the `mysqld.cnf` is read properly, but `/usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"` reveals one of the conf files is the correct one.

Is there a way to do this via a mysql statement - and how looks it like?
The most easiest way, making a symbolic link in the filesystem, doesn't work (anymore).

Comment: Perhaps you meant `mysqld.cnf`.

Comment: Yes, was just a typo here. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick James' answer made me aware that (whyever) the conf file was not read. So I copied `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. That one *is* read fine.
I then had to define (in `my.cnf`):

```
[mysqld]
innodb_tmpdir=$yourNewTmpPath
innodb_temp_data_file_path=$yourNewTmpPath/ibtmp1:50M:autoextend:max:50G
innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir=$yourNewTmpPath
...
```

Substitute `$yourNewTmpPath` with your new temp directory. (Adopt your `innodb_temp_data_file_path` parameters at your need (you may not need `50G` for `autoextend`)).

Restart `mysqld`.

You can evaluate if the settings are properly consumed by:

```
mysql> SELECT @@innodb_temp_data_file_path;
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| @@innodb_temp_data_file_path                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| $yourNewTmpPath/ibtmp1:50M:autoextend:max:50G |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I could alter a 160GB table with `... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;`. On my NFS mount it produces some temporary `.nfs0000...` files, which are removed from time to time and created again. I think at most they needed around 50GB at a time. I also watched IO operations of `mysqld` (using `iotop -oPa`) which amounts to >1TB for write operations and again >1TB for read operations.

So, key here was to copy the config file to a place where it is indeed consumed - and use the proper variables and values for them.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqld --help --verbose
```

At about line 13, it will say where the config file is.  It is probably not spelled the way you spelled it.  Mine says

```
...
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
...
```

Comment: Mine too - and in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` it says ''!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
'' where two files resist :"default-auth-override.cnf" and "mysqld.cnf".

Comment: Interstingly, ` /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` is ignored - I have copied it to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and is now taking into account. So thx for insisting!

Comment: However, mysql refuses to start when `my.cnf` has the entry `innodb_temporary=$nfs3Dir`. Unfortunately no further messages are shown besides " mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE" . Is it not allowed to point `innodb_temporary` to an `nfs (version3)` mount ?

Comment: Hm. I had to assign to `innodb_temp_data_file_path` not only a path but  also the size, e.g like`=$path/ibtmp1:50M:autoextend:max:50G` .  Now at least `mysql> SELECT @@innodb_temp_data_file_path;` shows the new location `$path/ibtmp1` while `mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME='innodb_temporary'\G` still onyl references `./ibtmp1`. Gonna test this.

Comment: Those dollar signs smell like something to fill in -- was a script supposed to replace them?

Comment: I just used them here as variables to avoid pasting real data , to be generic. In the scripts I use no variables but real paths.

Comment: Any directories mentioned need write permission for the directory itself, plus read and search for all directories above it.